# Feature Extraction with Resnet 152 tensorflow Keras transfer learning

Tags: tensorflow, keras, feature-extraction, resnet, transfer-learning

I am trying to do feature extraction with TensorFlow. In short, I'm attempting to reproduce **step 3** in [ATTEND-GAN Model](https://github.com/omidmnezami/Style-GAN) that linked to the given provided code base in  prepro.py in [Show Attend and Tell Repo](https://github.com/yunjey/show-attend-and-tell)

```
vggnet = Vgg19(vgg_model_path)
vggnet.build()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    for split in ['train', 'val', 'test']:
        anno_path = './data/%s/%s.annotations.pkl' % (split, split)
        save_path = './data/%s/%s.features.hkl' % (split, split)
        annotations = load_pickle(anno_path)
        image_path = list(annotations['file_name'].unique())
        n_examples = len(image_path)

        all_feats = np.ndarray([n_examples, 196, 512], dtype=np.float32)

        for start, end in zip(range(0, n_examples, batch_size),
                              range(batch_size, n_examples + batch_size, batch_size)):
            image_batch_file = image_path[start:end]
            image_batch = np.array(map(lambda x: ndimage.imread(x, mode='RGB'), image_batch_file)).astype(
                np.float32)
            feats = sess.run(vggnet.features, feed_dict={vggnet.images: image_batch})
            all_feats[start:end, :] = feats
            print ("Processed %d %s features.." % (end, split))

        # use hickle to save huge feature vectors
        hickle.dump(all_feats, save_path)
        print ("Saved %s.." % (save_path))
```

In the attempt to do the preprocessing in step 3, I'm trying to change the vgg19 model with resnet152 by changing and extract the feature with res5c layer by changing

> vggnet = Vgg19(vgg_model_path)

with

```
import tensorflow as tf


rn152 = tf.keras.applications.ResNet152V2(
    include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=(224, 224, 3)
)
new_input = rn152.input
hidden_layer = rn152.layers[-1].output

# image_model.summary()

image_features_extract_model = tf.keras.Model(new_input, hidden_layer)
```

Note: Please tell me if i'm approaching this wrong or the code above is not right or need some adjustments.

In my code above, I think I have extracted the features. But, I'm stuck on how to integrate it into the tf.Session block. Specifically on this line :

> feats = sess.run(vggnet.features, feed_dict={vggnet.images: image_batch})

Please kindly help me in attempting this task. Thank you for your help.